# base64 result not what I expected - esp32 Huzzah32 feather

Tags: base64, sha256, arduino-esp32

I am a hobbyist and I am working way outside my level of knowledge. I have searched high and low for an answer and spend several hours amending code - but I cannot get this to produce the result I expected.

Please excuse me if I don't use the correct terminoloy - I am learning !

I use sha256 on **ABCD1234** and get the result

1635c8525afbae58c37bede3c9440844e9143727cc7c160bed665ec378d8a262

I then try use base64 to get

**MTYzNWM4NTI1YWZiYWU1OGMzN2JlZGUzYzk0NDA4NDRlOTE0MzcyN2NjN2MxNjBiZWQ2NjVlYzM3OGQ4YTI2MgogIA==**

but I get this instead

**FjXIUlr7rljDe+3jyUQIROkUNyfMfBYL7WZew3jYomI=**

WHat am I doing wrong - thank you in adavance.

```
#include "mbedtls/md.h"
#include "mbedtls/base64.h"

void setup(){
 
  Serial.begin(115200);
  char *payload = "ABCD1234";
  byte shaResult[32];
 
  mbedtls_md_context_t ctx;
  mbedtls_md_type_t md_type = MBEDTLS_MD_SHA256;
 
  const size_t payloadLength = strlen(payload);         
 
  mbedtls_md_init(&ctx);
  mbedtls_md_setup(&ctx, mbedtls_md_info_from_type(md_type), 0);
  mbedtls_md_starts(&ctx);
  mbedtls_md_update(&ctx, (const unsigned char *) payload, payloadLength);
  mbedtls_md_finish(&ctx, shaResult);
  mbedtls_md_free(&ctx);

  // https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/sha256.html
  // sha256 expected
  // 1635c8525afbae58c37bede3c9440844e9143727cc7c160bed665ec378d8a262
  
  for(int i= 0; i< sizeof(shaResult); i++){
      char str[3];
 
      sprintf(str, "%02x", (int)shaResult[i]);
      Serial.print(str);
  }
Serial.println();
  
  // https://www.base64encode.org/
  // base64 expected
  // MTYzNWM4NTI1YWZiYWU1OGMzN2JlZGUzYzk0NDA4NDRlOTE0MzcyN2NjN2MxNjBiZWQ2NjVlYzM3OGQ4YTI2MgogIA==

  // Actual result
  // FjXIUlr7rljDe+3jyUQIROkUNyfMfBYL7WZew3jYomI=
  unsigned char output[65];
  size_t outlen=65;
  mbedtls_base64_encode(output,  sizeof(output), &outlen, (unsigned char *)shaResult, sizeof(shaResult));
  // null-terminate the output string
  output[outlen] = 0;
  Serial.println((const char*)output);
}
 
void loop(){}
```

Comment: The longer string (`MTYzNWM4NT...`) contains the base64 encoded Hex-String (`1635c8525afba...`), the shorter one (`FjXIUlr7rljD...`) contains the Base64 encoded bytes (binary data). So instead of encoding `shaResult` to base64, which produces the shorter string, you need to encode `str`, which contains the hex-encoded string.   But it's quite unusual that you need the longer version because that means that you have a double text encoding, first to hex and then base64 on top of it.

Comment: Thank you jps - that makes sense - I need to think how to achieve that - but at least I know which direction to head in...

The application is getting access to the api of a Huawei router.

Note how the router wants the password to be the following:
1) Hashed by SHA256, then the raw output base64 encoded.
2) The username is appended with the result of the above, 
   AND the current token. 
3) The string from above (point 2) is then hashed by SHA256 again, 
   and the raw output is once again base64 encoded.

Comment: *then the raw output base64 encoded* - but that sounds more like direct binary to base64, which you already have as your current actual result. But I have no clue about Huawai routers. This [online decoder](https://base64.guru/converter/decode/hex) (which I used to inspect your base64 strings) might be helpful for you.